# Faster way to perform sort by index on pandas group

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with name(person_name), color(shirt_color) as columns
Each person wears a shirt with a certain color on a particular day (number of days can be arbitrary)

eg input:

```
name    color
----------------
John    White
John    White
John    Blue
John    Blue
John    White
Tom     Blue
Tom     Blue
Tom     Green
Tom     Black
Jerry   Black
Jerry   Blue
Jerry   Black
```

I need to find the best colored shirt worn by each person,
according to best_color_order eg result:

```
name    color
-------------
Jerry   Blue
John    White
Tom     Green
```

I am doing the following :

```
best_color_order = ['White', 'Green', 'Blue', 'Black']

best_color_list = [[name, list(group['color']).sort(key=best_color_order.index)[0]]
                    for name, group in df.groupby(by='name', sort=False, as_index=False)]

best_color_df = pd.DataFrame(best_color_list, columns=['name', 'color'])
```

Is there a faster way to do this if I have millions of records?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert the column `color` to an [ordered categorical](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Categorical.html) so it will sort in your desired order, then sort the values by `color`, and finally `groupby` and take the `first` value for each name:

```
best_color_order = ['White', 'Green', 'Blue', 'Black']

df['color'] = pd.Categorical(df['color'], categories = best_color_order, ordered=True)

df.sort_values('color').groupby('name').first()

       color
name        
Jerry   Blue
John   White
Tom    Green
```

**[EDIT]**: A faster way might be to do the same, but instead of groupby, just drop the duplicate `name`s and keep the first (which is the default for the function `drop_duplicates`):

```
best_color_order = ['White', 'Green', 'Blue', 'Black']

df['color'] = pd.Categorical(df['color'], categories = best_color_order, ordered=True)

df.sort_values('color').drop_duplicates('name')

     name  color
0    John  White
7     Tom  Green
10  Jerry   Blue
```

Comment: thanks @sacul , i ran cprofiler and seams like there is not a major increase in performance, on millions of groups

Comment: @astrobiologist, I added an alternative, should be faster with millions of groups. Takes about 0.5 seconds on my computer with 10000 groups and 1000000 records, as opposed to my first strategy which takes about 5.2 seconds for the same records

Comment: thats a nice solution. Thanks!